# Finding the minimum value of a function using mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, inequality

'If $f$ is a differentiable function for all $x$ such that $f'(x) \geq x, f(0)=2$, then find the minimum value of $f(3)$ using mean value theorem'

Using definite integration, the minimum value comes out to be $13/2$. But when I tried using mean value theorem, all I got is another inequality. The problem I found in using the second method was that the derivative is not greater than a constant value, but instead $f'(x) \geq x$. Please suggest some approaches of tackling this problem.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint: Use the idea of Riemann Sum***
The reason for that is we know the disadvantage of the mean value theorem here is that the theory of mean value theorem provide a method of exsistance but here we need to be precise.
Here is how I do it.
*Step one: take the partition*
To make the process easier, I choose to take the partition averagely.
I set $x_0=0,x_1=\frac{3}{n}...x_i=\frac{3i}{n}...x_n=3$.
After that, I successfully split the interval into equal lengthed pieces.
and I also name $\Delta x$ to be $\frac{3}{n}$.
Now we look at the interval $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$, we will use the mean value theorem here.
There exists c$\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ that $f'(c)=\frac{f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)}{x_{k+1}-x_k}=\frac{f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)}{\Delta x}$, and we now have to take the limit.
We know when k is approaching to the infinity, then $\Delta x$ will go to zero, then we will find that the interval $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ is becoming smaller and smaller, so that we can approximate c to be $x_k$.
**Now we have all the process below are under the condition that n$\rightarrow\infty$.**
so we have $f'(c)=\frac{f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)}{x_{k+1}-x_k}=\frac{f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)}{\Delta x}$,
$f'(x_k)=\frac{f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)}{\Delta x}$
we know that $f'(x)\geq x$
So $x_k\leq \frac{f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)}{\Delta x}$
Because we now that $\Delta x $ is very small, so i will write it as dx.
Then we will have $x_kdx\leq f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k) $
*Step two:take the sum*
We now take the sum of the left side of the inequility which is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\Sigma_{k=0}^nx_kdx]=\int_{0}^{3}xdx=\frac{9}2$
When the other side of the inequility after the sum up is $\Sigma_{k=0}^n[f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)]=f(3)-f(0)=f(3)-2$
So now we have $\frac{9}{2}\leq f(3)-2 $
So finally we proved that $f(3)\geq\frac{13}{2}$.
Hope it will help.